# CLS score in Page Speed vs Search Console

Tags: google-search-console

Google Search Console said my website has some pages with CLS and FLP issues. After fixing them, they are ok in Page Speed:
[image: Page Speed score]

After the revalidation in Google Search Console and waiting for several weeks, Google said those page failed again - CLS is still over 0.25s.

I don't know what else can be done to fix them. Page Speed Lab Data is fine but Google Search Console still said it's over 0.25s.

Does it mean if someone with a very slow connection visiting my website and have a poor CLS or LCP score, Google Search Console will count this as field data and fail my website? How can I possibly fix this?

Comment: Cumulative layout shift isn't measured in seconds.   Its a measure of how many elements in the page move after they are initially rendered, and by how much.   It doesn't depend much on connection speed but it can depend on browser size and other factors.   See https://speedcurve.com/blog/google-cumulative-layout-shift/